# Unable to connect via Wowza server

Tags: ios, streaming, rtmp, wowza

I am trying to run [MediaLibDemos3x](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos3x) by cloning on my Mac. I have downloaded and installed 'Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1' successfully. Whenever I am trying to 'Connect' on Simulator, I see following in log:

```
2016-06-07 18:23:47.368 RTMPStreamPublisher[2627:218022] connectControl: host = rtmp://192.168.3.1:1935
2016-06-07 18:23:47.369 RTMPStreamPublisher[2627:218022] initVideoCapture -> input/output is not supported
2016-06-07 18:23:47.381 RTMPStreamPublisher[2627:223059] $$$$$$ stateChangedEvent: 0 = NetConnection.Connect.Rejected [T]
```

and when on iOS device:

```
2016-06-07 18:37:59.157 RTMPStreamPublisher[321:34195] RTMPClient -> eventFailed: code = -7, description = fault code = 61 < The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused >, calls = 0
2016-06-07 18:37:59.168 RTMPStreamPublisher[321:33625] $$$$$$ connectFailedEvent: -7 = fault code = 61 < The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused >, [M]
```

Here is the setting : 
Host - Server

```
192.168.3.1 Host - Port 1935
```

What is wrong here? Am I missing anything? Please help me to run this.